# Problem with EXPRESS and CORS - Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: node.js, express, cors

When I pass a single url to my Cors options, my API return the Access-Control-Allow-Origin with this url:

```
 app.use(cors({
  origin: 'https://fakeUrl.net/',
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
}));
```

[image: Header Exemple]

But when I pass a list, the express don't return the header:

```
 var allowedOrigins = ['https://fakeUrl.net','https://fakeUrl2.net/'];

app.use(cors({
  origin: function(origin: any, callback: any){
    if(!origin){
      console.log('Cors indefinido: ' + origin);
      return callback(null, true);
    }
    if(allowedOrigins.indexOf(origin) === -1){
      console.log('Cors fora da lista: ' + origin);
      var msg = 'The CORS policy for this site does not ' +
                'allow access from the specified Origin. Return 12221511';
      return callback(new Error(msg), false);
    }
    console.log('Cors dentro da lista: ' + origin);
    return callback(null, true);
  },
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
}));
```

Or like this:

```
 app.use(cors({
  origin: ['https://fakeUrl.net','https://fakeUrl2.net/'],
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
}));
```

Just don't Work.

I believe it's a problem in Express, I already open a Ticket on github for the team, but it's closed now.

Anyone can handly it problem?

Comment: "But when I pass a list, the express don't return the header" — What **does** it do? You've got a number of log statements there but you haven't told us what they output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function to customize the cors, instead of passing it as a method:

```
const whitelist = ['http://something.com', 'http://example.com'];

    const corsOptionsCheck = (req, callback) => {
    let corsOptions;

    let isDomainAllowed = whitelist.indexOf(req.header('Origin')) !== -1;

    if (isDomainAllowed) {
        // Enable CORS for this request
        corsOptions = { origin: true }
    } else {
        // Disable CORS for this request
        corsOptions = { origin: false }
    }
    callback(null, corsOptions)
}

app.use(cors(corsOptionsCheck));
```

Comment: I need a return header Access-Control-Allow-Origin. The validation is ok.

Comment: This code will allow CORS if the origin header includes any domains exist n the whitelist array. You can check the response header Access-Control-Allow-Origin. For more details you can check here how this works: https://web.dev/cross-origin-resource-sharing/

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately I need to force the header in return:

```
var allowedOrigins = ['https://fakeUrl.net','https://fakeUrl2.net/'];

let origin = (req.headers.origin != undefined && req.headers.origin.length > 0)? (req.headers.origin ?? "") : (req.headers.host ?? "");
    let theOrigin = "";
    
    ALLOWED_ORIGINS.forEach(element => {
      if(element.toLowerCase().includes(origin?.toLowerCase() ?? ""))theOrigin = element;
    });

if(!theOrigin && theOrigin.length > 0){
      res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", theOrigin);
      res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    }
```

I've trying many exemples that I found and no one works perfectly.